# Issue with bidirectional one-to-one relationship trying to INSERT instead of UPDATE in Java EclipseLink

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, one-to-one

I'm having trouble understanding why bidirectional relationship is not working here quite as I expect it to. When I persist owning side after setting relationships both ways, cascading takes place and an 'INSERT INTO INVERSESIDE' SQL statement is executed. This causes exception to be thrown from trying to add a duplicate PK into inverse side entity's table.

I'd assume there should be an 'UPDATE' statement instead, as the inverse side entity is already in DB and - as far as my rookie guts can tell - is fully managed by JPA.

**Database mockup:**

```
TABLE INVERSESIDE
  id

TABLE OWNINGSIDE
  id
  inverseside_id
```

**Java mockup:**

DAO interfaces

```
@Repository
public interface isDAO extends JpaRepository<InverseSide, Long>

@Repository
public interface osDAO extends JpaRepository<OwningSide, Long>
```

Entity classes

```
public class InverseSide {
  private Long id;

  @OneToOne(optional = true, mappedBy = "inverse")
  private OwningSide owner;

  public void setOwner(OwningSide os) {
    owner = os;
  }
}

public class OwningSide {
  private Long id;

  @OneToOne(optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private InverseSide inverse;

  public void setInverse(InverseSide is) {
    inverse = is;
    inverse.setOwner(this);
  }
}
```

Test code

```
InverseSide inverse = isDAO.findAll().get(0); // Returns a valid object with id 1000
OwningSide owner = new OwningSide();

owner.setInverse(inverse);
osDAO.save(owner); // Exception

/*
  org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: 
  Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is 
  javax.persistence.RollbackException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse 
  Persistence Services - 2.7.0.v20170811-d680af5): 
  org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
  Internal Exception: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Unique index or primary 
  key violation: "PRIMARY KEY ON PUBLIC.INVERSESIDE(ID)"; SQL statement:
  INSERT INTO INVERSESIDE (ID, ...
  Error Code: 23505
  Call: INSERT INTO INVERSESIDE (ID, ...
          bind => [1000, ...
*/
```

**UPDATE**

Inverse side INSERT is due to owning side being new to - and consequently unmanaged by - JPA. In other words, even though IS was known from JPA's point of view, persisting unmanaged OS led to also its connected IS being treated as unmanaged.

Thus, the answer is to persist new inverseless owner first, then complete the relationship both ways and finally persist the owner again:

```
InverseSide inverse = isDAO.findAll().get(0);
OwningSide owner = new OwningSide();

osDAO.save(owner);

owner.setInverse(inverse);
osDAO.save(owner);
```

Perhaps I should have anticipated this behavior. However, it doesn't feel completely intuitive, and none of the sources I studied mentioned this.

Answer (score 0):

Most instances of this type of problem comes due to the fact that the object inverse is probably detached.  Barring specific transactional boundaries, each call to the repository methods is its own transaction, and so the return value is detached.  And so it thinks it's a new object, and thus you get insert instead of update.

However, even if you have transactional boundaries set properly, I don't think ANY JPA implementation will do what you want it to do.  It's not a simple matter of updating IS.  You're expectations, in pseudo code:

```
select OS where OS.is.id = :isID

update OS set is = null where OS.is.id = :isID

insert OS (:newOS)
```

The first two statements simply isn't in the realm of responsibility for the entity manager.  This implementation seems to be more appropriate for a `ManyToOne` relationship.  Otherwise, you should load the other OS, remove it's attachment to the IS, save that, create your new OS, attach the IS, and save that.  All in the same transaction.

Comment: It's actually not _replacing_ owner for inverse side that I expect to succeed here, but _adding_ OS to an ownerless IS and persisting that connection via OS' DAO. I see I failed to mention this in my opening post. As for individual transactions, it's not the case here. I found the reason and updated my post to include it.